An integral in calculating the fine structure energy
In computing the LS Coupling and calculate the energy difference of the fine structure, an approximate way is to use the Bohr model and calculate the magnetic energy of the magnetic moment.
$$\begin{align*}
E_{LS} &= - \vec{\mu_s}\cdot\vec{B_l}\\
&=\frac{g_s}{2}\frac{\mu_0Ze^2}{8\pi m_e^2 r^3}(\vec{S}\cdot\vec{L})\\
&=\frac{g_s}{2}\frac{\mu_0Ze^2}{8\pi m_e^2 r^3}\frac{j(j+1)-l(l+1)-s(s+1)}{2}\hbar^2
\end{align*}$$
Here the $\frac{1}{r^3}$ term is better to use the value calculated from Schrodinger Equation than using the Bohr model.
My textbook has this integral but I don't know how to do this integral.
$$\begin{align*}
\langle\frac{1}{r^3}\rangle &= \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{r^3} |R_{nl}(r)|^2r^2dr\\
&=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{r} |R_{nl}(r)|^2dr\\
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{r}[(\frac{2Z}{n}\frac{r}{a_0})^lL_{n+l}^{2l+1}(\frac{2Z}{n}\frac{r}{a_0})\exp(\frac{-Z}{n}\frac{r}{a_0})]^2dr\\
&=\frac{1}{l(l+\frac12)(l+1)}\frac{Z^3}{n^3a_0^3}
\end{align*}$$
Where the Associated Laguerre polynomials follow the definition here.
My attempt, let $x = \frac{2Z}{n}\frac{r}{a_0}$, and do the integral by part 3 times:
$$\begin{align*}
&\quad\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{r}[(\frac{2Z}{n}\frac{r}{a_0})^lL_{n+l}^{2l+1}(\frac{2Z}{n}\frac{r}{a_0})\exp(\frac{-Z}{n}\frac{r}{a_0})]^2dr\\
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{(\frac{2Z}{n}\frac{r}{a_0})}(\frac{2Z}{n}\frac{r}{a_0})^{2l}[L_{n+l}^{2l+1}(\frac{2Z}{n}\frac{r}{a_0})]^2\exp(\frac{-2Z}{n}\frac{r}{a_0})d(\frac{2Z}{n}\frac{r}{a_0})\\
&=\int_0^\infty(x)^{2l-1}\exp(-x)[L_{n+l}^{2l+1}(x)]^2dx\\
&=(-1)\frac{1}{2l}\int_0^\infty(x)^{2l}\frac{d}{dx}\{\exp(-x)[L_{n+l}^{2l+1}(x)]^2\}dx\\
&=\frac{1}{2l}\frac{1}{2l+1}\int_0^\infty(x)^{2l+1}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\{\exp(-x)[L_{n+l}^{2l+1}(x)]^2\}dx\\
&=(-1)\frac{1}{2l}\frac{1}{2l+1}\frac{1}{2l+2}\int_0^\infty(x)^{2l+2}\frac{d^3}{dx^3}\{\exp(-x)[L_{n+l}^{2l+1}(x)]^2\}dx\\
&=\frac{-1}{8}\frac{1}{l(l+\frac12)(l+1)}\int_0^\infty(x)^{2l+2}\frac{d^3}{dx^3}\{\exp(-x)[L_{n+l}^{2l+1}(x)]^2\}dx
\end{align*}$$
This is the best I can get, but the differentiation term expand a lot and there is no way to get the $\frac{Z}{na_0}$
Here is a similar content from material in MIT OpenCourse

Edit on 2024/12/5:
With support from @dennismoore94 in comment, about the Kramers' Relation, I realize the result and the way to get the result is beyond my current knowledge. I will comeback to this one day.
Here is the source of my elementary "Modern Physics" textbook, wrote and published in Traditional Chinese. There is no further explanation in how the integral is done, so I am still curious if it is true.


Just double checking -- defining $x=2Zr / n a_0$, and up to overall consants, the integral you are asking about is
$$
\int_0^\infty x^{2\ell-1}\left(L_{n+\ell}^{2\ell+1}(x)\right)^2\exp\left(-x\right)?
$$

Also are you happy using Eq 13 in https://solitaryroad.com/c681.html, or do you want to basically derive Eq 13?

@Andrew I don't know if there is another way to substitute the $2Zr/na_0$, since there is no hint in how to solve the integral. The final solution looks like this:
$$\frac{1}{2l(2l+1)(2l+2)}(\frac{2Z}{na_0})^3$$
Maybe there is something I miss before I define x. And sure if Eq13 in the bottom of the page helps but I'm afraid it might not, the $x^{m+1}e^{-x}L_n^m$ is also what I am trying to achieve.

All I did in writing the integral down in my comment was to take this expression you wrote down
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{r}[(\frac{2Z}{n}\frac{r}{a_0})^lL_{n+l}^{2l+1}(\frac{2Z}{n}\frac{r}{a_0})exp(\frac{-Z}{n}\frac{r}{a_0})]^2dr
$$
define $x=2 Z r / n a_0$, and substitute $x$ for $r$ in this expression (ignoring an overall prefactor). In the form of my comment, it seems pretty obvious that Eq 13 will be useful.

@Andrew
About the Eq13, I derived it by myself about 3 weeks ago. See this

OK, if you're happy with Eq 13, I think the rest is just doing the algebra carefully to see that your original integral can be done using Eq 13, and keeping track of all the prefactors, as well as $n$'s and $\ell$'s needed to evaluate the factorials.

@Andrew Yes the integral should be this
$$\int_0^\infty x^{2l-1}(L_{n+l}^{2l+1}(x))^2exp(-x)dx$$

Cool! Yeah so from there I think you just use Eq 13, and the factorials should simplify if you keep track of everything.

@Andrew I think the $\frac{d^3}{dx^3}(e^{-x}L^2)$ term is not going to work.
The first derivative is like this: $\frac{d}{dx}(e^{-x}L^2) = e^{-x}L(2L'-L)$ where by Eq6, $(L_n^m)'=L_n^{m+1}$, when $m$ are different, there is no integral result to use.

Oh, I see what you mean. I'm sorry, I was just trying to simplify your question down to a specific integral, but I see the problem is that the power of $x$ doesn't match the upper index of $L^m_n$ in a way where you can directly use Eq 13. I'll have to think about that, although I suppose one brute force approach would be to use Eq 12 to reduce the problem to a sum of terms like $x^m e^{-x}$, each of which can be integrated. Anyway your issue is clearer to me now, thank you!

Do you insist on calculating $\langle r^{-3}\rangle$ the brute force way? Such expectation values can be readily derived from the Kramers relations.

For reference, you should use \exp to write it as the operator $\exp$ instead of what appears to be the product of $e$, $x$ and $p$. Also, you can use \align commands to keep the equations aligned on the equals signs.

@dennismoore94 Thanks for providing the material, I didn't know this. I will take a closer look on this, but I am still curious if the integral can be done.

@KyleKanos Thanks for the tips, I am new to this site and the latex overleaf things. Appreciated!

For what it is worth, if you replace the Laguerre polynomials with their generating function the resulting integral may be more tractable. Since the generating function represent a linear combination of the polynomials you can evaluate the integral and then use the procedure to extract the polynomial to obtain the result for a specific polynomial.
